# NSString variable's content getting lost

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring

I have a NSString variable - it has a text - apple in one of my methods - `viewDidLoad`.

The same variable's text becomes

```
<UIButtonContent: 0x4f8a190 Title = (null), Image = <UIImage: 0x4f5da60>, Background = (null), TitleColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1, ShadowColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0.5>
```

in another method which is executed after the first method. Why is the content getting lost?

The code

```
merchant = [retrieveBusinessData businessName]
```

`[retrieveBusinessData businessName]` returns a nsstring variable.

```
merchant = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [retrieveBusinessData businessName]];
```

This is the solution which solved my problem. I have posted in prince's reply

Comment: NSString is an immutable class, so it's impossible for its value to 'get lost'. Please post your code. Also, it is very difficult to tell what the "code" means in your post.

Comment: is the nsstring variable defined as a class member? is the variable allocated and retained properly? please reformat your question, until then -1.

Comment: psoft please find above the code - there was a problem with the assigning of the string - hence the problem.

Comment: alinoz - the code - NSString *merchant
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *merchant;

Comment: it has synthesize as well
@synthesize merchant;

Comment: That means absolutely nothing because you are not using it.  If you want to use it then you should say "self.merchant = ..." and not just "merchant = ..."

Comment: i had a doubt w.r.t this concept of self.merchant and merchant - what is the difference - i realized they can differentiate a local and global variable...Anyother differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

retain  NSString variable as NSString is an immutable class

```
[yourString retain];
```

Comment: i have assigned nonatomic and retain properties. Still same issue

Comment: i was using var = anotherString. The correct way of assigning it is var = [[nsstring alloc] initwithstringformat@"%@",anotherString]];...This solved the issue...nyways thnx for the suggestions

Comment: That line is redundant...Why do you need to go through all that just to get a string that is the same as another string?  You could just use var = [anotherString copy];

Comment: ya...copy might me a better solution...thnx

Comment: @borden - the issue pops up when i try to access this variable from the child class...there is a difference between just = assignment and nsstring alloc as we allocate memory to it...